# Branching and Maintaining Position

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex

In Oracle ApEx, I have 6 regions on one page. Within Region 5, I have a report with an edit button that branches to another page, where I can edit some details, hit the save button, which then returns me back to the original page, with the 6 regions.

On return though, it branches back to the top of the page, where region 1 is.

Is there any way of branching back to region 5 from where I initially pressed the edit button instead of scrolling to the top of the page? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this example page](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=35662:17).  It has 3 reports (all the same as it happens).  Each report has a link that takes you to another page with a Cancel button.  When you cancel, it returns to the first page and scrolls to the report you clicked from.

How it works:

1. In each of the report regions I added a named anchors in the HTML header like this:

   `<a name="REPORT1" />`
2. In the links for each report I pass a value like "REPORT1" to an item called P18_RETURN_ANCHOR in the second page (I made this item visible just to help you follow what I have done; in reality you would probably use a hidden item).
3. In the second page's Cancel button I branch back to page 17.  In the "with these values" property I put `#&P18_RETURN_ANCHOR.`  This has the effect of adding a tag like #REPORT1 to the end of the URL, which means "scroll down to the anchor named REPORT1". (This is standard browser behaviour, not Apex-specific.)

Comment: Hi Tony, appreciate your help again but I am not seeing the scrolling to the report you clicked from. I am using Chrome on Mac OS X. Is it suppose to scroll to that report header and place this at the top of the page as I'm not seeing the scrolling occuring? Thanks.

Comment: It scrolls so that the start of the report is visible.  It doesn't have to be at the top of the page, just where it can bee seen.  You should see a difference between returning to Report 1 and returning to Report 3?  I use Chrome too, and it works for me.